# How to pass a dictionary from makefile to jinja .j2 file

Tags: makefile, jinja2

I have a dictionary in makefile something like -

`${Dict} = [AccountId:{"Key": "x", "Value": "y"}, AccountId:{"Key": "x", "Value": "b"}]`

I am using [yasha](https://github.com/kblomqvist/yasha) and want to pass this dictionary to jinja using yasha

In the makefile, i have defined something like -
`yasha --tag_list=${Dict} -o test.yaml test.yaml.j2`

Within the jinja template however i am not able to access this dictionary.

In the jinja template i have tried
`{% for tag in tag_list %} name: test-{{ tag }}`

But it always returns blank which makes me think that my dictionary is not getting passed from makefile to jinja template correctly using yasha

Answer (score 0):

> I have a dictionary in makefile something like -
>
> ```
> ${Dict} = [AccountId:{"Key": "x", "Value": "y"}, AccountId:{"Key": "x", "Value": "b"}]
> ```

Well, no.  `make` knows nothing about dictionaries.  Also the `${...}` is not part of the name of a variable.  It is used for variable expansion, not as shown, for variable assignment.

So maybe you have a variable containing a *string* that has the form of a Python dict literal, like this:

```
Dict = [AccountId:{"Key": "x", "Value": "y"}, AccountId:{"Key": "x", "Value": "b"}]
```

> In the makefile, i have defined something like - `yasha --tag_list=${Dict} -o test.yaml test.yaml.j2`
>
> Within the jinja template however i am not able to access this
> dictionary.

Not surprising.  Even if your variable assignment were of the correct form for `make`,  the value is chock full of whitespace and other characters that are significant to the shell, which will be interpreted by the shell.  What you get will depend in part on what other files are in the directory, because to the shell, the `[]` delimit a character class for globbing.  Even if it passes through literally (on account of there being no files with single-character names) the shell will perform word splitting and quote removal on the result, which will also mess this up.  Depending on which shell `make` uses, there could be more.

When you write make recipes, as any time you're writing input to the shell, it is important to pay attention to proper quoting.  You can omit quotes where you **know** you don't need them, and it is conventional to do so, but here you do need quotes.  Probably best would be:

```
test.yaml:
        yasha --tag_list='$(Dict)' -o $@ $@.j2
```

Most important there is the single quotes (`'`) around the expansion of `Dict`.  Alternatively, you could put those in the variable's definition instead, and that might be even better.  Additional, mainly stylistic points include:

- Files to be generated by `make` should almost always be specified as the target of a rule for that generation.
- It is usually better to avoid repeating yourself, and in particular, in a rule's recipe, the name of the target should usually be expressed via the automatic variable `$@`.
- `make` variable expansion can be expressed with either curly braces (`${Dict}`) or parentheses (`$(Dict)`).  The two forms mean the same thing to `make`.  I recommend consistently using the latter for `make` variable expansion, to make it clear that that's really what you mean, as opposed to *shell* variable expansion.